# Does spring JPA support Custom value framework?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, persistence

I have a situation where I need to add multiple fields (with data type information) on run time and corresponding to that I have to persist values in database using spring-JPA.

I am not sure how can I get solution in JPA for this. Let me know If spring JPA support custom value framework or I need to find out some workaround.

adding some more information : 
for example in a job portal you can add n number of employer details and while retrieving this information, system should display information with corresponding employer in that portal. Similar kind of requirement exist in my project as well.

Like

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "tool name",
  "type": "Internal1",
  "width1": 100,
  "width2": 200,
  "height1": 100,
  "height2": 200,
  "description": "description",
  "custom1": "custom1",
  "custom2": "custom2"
}
```

now in this JSON user want to send n number of custom field so my system should be flexible enough to accept these changes.

From UI perspective my implementation should be abstract means whatever mapping or collection is used to POST this information in database but while fetching(GET) data should be in same JSON format.

I hope this use case may help to identify appropriate requirement.

Comment: You should clarify your question a bit more (adding examples of what you want to achieve may help).

Comment: @dunni I have added an example

Comment: Ok, i still don't understand, what you want, especially what you mean with "add multiple fields on run time". Do you mean relations in JPA (One-To-One, One-To-Many etc)?

Comment: @dunni I have added a sample json , I hope this may clear picture for you.